# Question about exponential distribution

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

> A factory manufactures a product with a life cycle that follows
>   the exponential distribution. Specify the parameter λ when it is known
>   that 80% of the products last at least 3 years.

And the answer is $=\frac{-ln(4/5)}{3} ≈ 0.07$.

I ran into this question while browsing the new textbook and I'm curious how they came up with that answer.

Comment: What do you know about the exponential distribution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf for the exponential distribution is $\lambda\cdot e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge 0$ (and $0$ elsewhere).

So your information works out to $\int_3^\infty \lambda\cdot e^{-\lambda x} dx=0.80$.

From here you can work out the integral and solve the resulting equation for $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.